# Asp.Net Session is null in ashx file

Tags: asp.net, session, httphandler

I am trying to access the **Session variable** in Asp.Net ashx handler as shown below.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Session["VariableName"] = Id;
    }
```

But the **context.Session** is always **Null** inside the above method. How do I access Session objects in ashx file?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You have to "implement" either [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate(VS.80).aspx) or [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate(VS.80).aspx), with former providing full access to session, and the latter providing read-only access.

I'm quoting "implement" here because these two are so-called "[marker interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)", which means they have no members.

Comment: Have an upvote good sir.  My only regret is that I can only give one.

Comment: Great! And about the "marker interfaces", wouldn't it be better if they made this as Annotations?

Comment: by "implement" Anton means having: public class ClassName : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState{...}

Answer (score 2):

In VB, implement the interfaces mentioned by Anton (IRequiresSessionState or IReadOnlySessionState) like this:

```
Public Class MyAshxFile

    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler
    Implements System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState ''need this for session variables
    Implements System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState ''need this for session variables
```