# get session value - ASP.NET Web Handler file

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I cannot get session value at ASHX file.
I had searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156524/asp-net-session-is-null-in-ashx-file/2156528#2156528) so I can solve my problem.

But I still cannot get session value.
Please let me get your suggestion.

[ASPX Design File]

```
...
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <iframe runat="server" id="iframepdf" height="600" width="800" src="./PDFViewer.ashx"></iframe>
</div>
</form>
...
```

[ASPX Code Behind]

```
...
namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class NameCard : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        Session["PDFFileName"] = @"D:\Test.pdf";
    }
}
}
```

As you see my code behind file,
 I set some value to session object.
And then, I write below ashx file.

[ASHX Code Behind]

```
...
namespace WebApplication1
{
public class PDFViewer : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {   
        context.Session["StackOverflow"] = "overflowing";  // This one give me output value as "overflowing"
        if (context.Session["PDFFileName"] != null) {  // My problem is this line, It always say null value ...
            context.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
            var PDFFileName = context.Session["PDFFileName"].ToString();                
            context.Response.WriteFile(PDFFileName);
            context.Response.End();
            context.Session["PDFFileName"] = string.Empty;
        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is your PageLoad always getting called before you ashx?

Comment: Sure, PageLoad run first before ashx load.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments in you code I interpret it that you get the `context.Session["StackOverflow"]` but not the `["PDFFileName"]` value? Is that correct? Put a breakpoint in the pages where you assign the session values and in the handler where you use them and run a debugger.

Maybe you've misspelled the keys? Remember that the keys are case sensetive.