# session state in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I'm going to save a variable in session by this:

```
context.Session["name"] = context.Request.Params["name"];
context.Response.Write(context.Session["name"]);
```

and the config file is this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
       <sessionState cookieless="false" mode="StateServer" timeout="10000"  
           stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424">
       </sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

but I got this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: How are you setting your `context` object?

Comment: Can you show us the context, pun intended, of where you are using the context? Also, have you put a breakpoint on the lines and examined the local variables?

Comment: context.Session["name"] = context.Request.Params["name"];

Comment: @SuperHornet - is this being used in an .aspx page, HttpHandler, etc.?

Comment: I used the code in a *.ashx file

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181408/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-in-ashx-file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156524/asp-net-session-is-null-in-ashx-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HttpHandler needs to implement the IRequireSessionState interface, otherwise Session is not available to the handler.

Comment: thanks, your answer is helpful