# How to send session from .ashx page to .aspx.cs page

Tags: asp.net

How to send session from .ashx page to .aspx.cs page.
I want to send a integer value through session.
Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `IReadOnlySessionState` or `IRequiresSessionState` following in your handler.

Suppose you have a handler name `MyHandler` then you need to use it as follows

```
 public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
```

and in that handler you need to write as follows

```
 public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
 {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session["yourKye"]="test123";
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

and you can use it in you page as normal session

```
string value=(string)Session["yourKye"];
```

Some similar questions

1. [How to access Session in .ashx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447196/how-to-access-session-in-ashx-file)
2. [HttpContext.Current.Session is null in Ashx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181408/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-in-ashx-file)
3. [Asp.Net Session is null in ashx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156524/asp-net-session-is-null-in-ashx-file)

In the ashx.cs file, also "implement" the interface [`System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx) or [`System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate).

Comment: For IReadOnlySessionState any namespace is required?

Comment: the name spaces are `System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState` and `System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState`

Comment: It is not working. string value=(string)Session["yourKye"]; Here string valee store return a null

Comment: @Sonali can you put your handler and the page in your question.

Comment: @ Șhȇkhaṝ 
I have used handler  to create a captcha. In handler using "Random" i have created a string and then it converted into image. And in my aspx file within Image src I call this ashx page just like  
<img src="image_captcha.ashx" id="imgCaptcha" /> 
Now I want to store the randomly created string in session for validate the captcha.

Comment: @Sonali not that your handler will be called after the page_load. The browser will request for the image once it is rendered. You can get the session values after postback. You can not get the value  of session before postback.